# Is it possible to reverse object from docChanges?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code :

```
firebase.firestore().collection(collection).doc(doc).collection(collection).orderBy("time", "desc").limit(10).onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
            var data = {
                id: change.doc.id,
                a: change.doc.data().a,
                b: change.doc.data().b,
                c: change.doc.data().c,
                d: change.doc.data().d,
                e: change.doc.data().e,
                f: change.doc.data().f,
            };

            if (change.type === "added") {
                msgData(data);
            }
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                msgData(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Is it possible to reverse object "change", so i can foreach the document from the smallest to the biggest time period?

If I change orderby to asc, the data I get is only the first 10 data. Meanwhile, what I want is to get the 10 most recent data sequences from smallest to largest time period. and what I'm thinking of is to reverse the "change" object that is got from the docChanges function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docChanges()` returns an array, so you can reverse it with [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```
querySnapshot.docChanges().reverse().forEach(...
```